# Ansible failed to transfer file to /command

Tags: ansible

Recently I have been using ansible for a wide variety of automation. However, during testing for automatic tomcat6 restart on specific webserver boxes. I came across this new error that I can't seem to fix.

```
FAILED => failed to transfer file to /command
```

Looking at documentation said its because of sftp-server not being in the sshd_config, however it is there.

Below is the command I am running to my webserver hosts.

```
ansible all -a "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart" -u user --ask-pass --sudo --ask-sudo-pass
```

There is a .ansible hidden folder on each of the boxes so I know its making to them but its not executing the command.

Running -vvvv gives me this after:

```
EXEC ['sshpass', '-d10', 'ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-vvv', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o',    'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'GSSAPIAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PubkeyAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=user', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.10.10.103', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1400791384.19-262170576359689 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1400791384.19-262170576359689 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1400791384.19-262170576359689'"]
```

then

```
10.10.10.103 | FAILED => failed to transfer file to /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1400791384.19-262170576359689/command
```

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Thanks,

---

*Edit:*

To increase Googleability, here is another manifestation of the error that the chosen answer fixes.

Running the command `ansible-playbook -i inventory hello_world.yml` gives this warning for every host.

```
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [host.example.com]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
```

And when you rerun the command as `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible-playbook -i inventory hello_world.yml` the only extra information you get is:

```
>>>sftp> put /var/folders/nc/htqkfk6j6h70hlxrr43rm4h00000gn/T/tmpxEWCe5 /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487430536.22-28138635532013/command.py
```

Comment: Could you please post the task that failed?

Comment: @ProfHase85 It fails to transfer the command file to .ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp..../command. Above I have the ansible command i am running.  `ansible all -a "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart" -u user --ask-pass --sudo --ask-sudo-pass`

Comment: can you also check the permissions on the ~/.ansible dir and its subdirectories on the remote machine?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

do you have sftp subsystem enabled in sshd on the remote server?
You can check it in /etc/sshd/sshd_config, the config file name depends on your distribution…anyway, look there for:

```
Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

If this line is commented-out, the sftp is disabled.
To fix it, you can either enable sftp, or change Ansible configuration.
I prefer the Ansible configuration change, take a look at ansible.cfg and add/change:

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
```

Comment: I already had `scp_if_ssh=True` in the `[defaults]` section of `ansible.cfg` and it didn't stop the error. Creating an `[ssh_connection]` section for it did. Much appreciated!

Comment: Dang, you just helped me after 2 hours of headache. Thank you so much. Had a 20.04 VM I just created and was trying to run an Ansible playbook. As soon as I restarted ssh, it worked.

Comment: Fresh install of CentOS 7 with Python3 installed.  I show Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server but Ansible complains about sftp not working.  If I run again with ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1, the stdout shows sftp succeeding.

Answer (score 8):

### Without touching `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

If only one host is affected, then this can be remedied **on a per host basis** in the `hosts` file as follows:

```
alias ansible_host=192.168.1.102 ansible_ssh_transfer_method=scp
```

This solution requires `ansible` version 2.3 or higher.

[[Source]](https://serverfault.com/a/852184/175321)

Comment: Possible values: `smart|sftp|scp|piped`

Answer (score 5):

Although it is true that this *used to work* back in '14 when **@stibi** solved the problem initially:

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
```

It is now superseded by the following line in ansible.cfg, which was referred to above as an inline hosts option by **@Serge Stroobandt**:

```
[ssh_connection]
transfer_method = scp
```

where possible values for `scp` are:

```
sftp  = use sftp to transfer files
scp   = use scp to transfer files
piped = use 'dd' over SSH to transfer files
smart = try sftp, scp, and piped, in that order [default]
```

When you specify `scp` instead of using the default, you avoid the transfer mechanism warning about `sftp`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently received a message like this for an entirely different reason. I had some stray text that was the result of a `cd -` command that I had in my `~/.bashrc` file. I fixed this issue by filtering its output like this:

#### my ~/.bashrc

```
...
cd ~/ansible/hacking/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && . env-setup -q && cd - > /dev/null 2>&1
...
```

Without those redirects of the cd commands to `/dev/null` I was getting this message.

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [app02]
ok: [app03]
fatal: [app01]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "failed to transfer file to /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1474747432.93-129438354708729/setup:\n\n/home/admin\n"}
```

#### my ansible.cfg

The other interesting details from my situation are that I'm already using this in my `ansible.cfg` file:

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
```

And the server in the list with the issue, app01, is the same server where I'm running the Ansible playbook from.

The bit of text at the end of my error message:

> 74747432.93-129438354708729/setup:\n\n/home/admin\n"}

is what clued me into my issue. That's the output from `cd ...` when it runs during login when my `~/.bashrc` file is being processed.

Comment: I had similar symptoms, with a fairly simple .bashrc file (Ansible transfer failed).  I moved .bashrc to bashrc (disabling it) and symptoms disappeared.  Moved code from .bashrc to .bash_profile since it checks for interactive session already.

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS8 I had to replace this line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

with

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Then restart sshd service with this command:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: This solution works when you are logging in as a non-root user and are using `become: yes`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work:

Step 1:

In the host file `(/etc/ansible/hosts)` use the  `ipaddress` as `"root@192.168.1.102"` instead of `"192.168.1.102"`.

Step 2:

Uncomment the property in `"/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg"` file.

```
scp_if_ssh=True
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try this solution:

```
rm -rf ~/.ansible
```

And then

```
ansible-galaxy install cbrunnkvist.ansistrano-symfony-deploy --force
```

After try again

```
ansible-playbook -i  etc/deploy/config/inventory.yml etc/deploy/deploy.yml
```

Comment: This does not explain why it's supposed to help, suggests to install 3rd party code and uses `--force`.